# Unable to set up XMPP with smack 4.1.6 on android studio and ejabberd 16.04 windows localhost

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, smack

Am a newbie to XMPP, Am trying to setup XMPP connection from my android device to ejabberd-16.04 server in android studio. But facing issues at login with username and password.

I have imported the code from https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/57209

am getting this error 
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

my XMPP connection details are :

```
private static final String DOMAIN = "localhost";
private static final String HOST = "192.168.1.xxx";
private static final int PORT = 5222;
private String userName ="admin@localhost";
private String passWord = "admin";
```

The same credentials are working when I tried to connect from mobile browser.

XMPP Connection code :

```
   XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder =      XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
  configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(userName, passWord);
  configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
  configBuilder.setResource("Android");
  configBuilder.setServiceName(DOMAIN);
  configBuilder.setHost(HOST);
  configBuilder.setPort(PORT);
   //configBuilder.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
   connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
   connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);
```

Comment: It's more related to studio configuration. You basically need to configure ur studio to access localhost. Try to resolve the issue for connecting to localhost. And the issue will be solved.